# How should I go about learning android?

Tags: java, android, game-engine

I have a couple questions for those of you out there that do android programming. How did you learn to program android? More specifically how do you program a game? Do I need programs other than eclipse? Alright thank you in advance for your expertise.  Forgive me if this is a stupid question.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/index.html helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

[Beginning Android Games](http://www.apress.com/9781430230427) might help you.
It offers everything you need to join the ranks of successful Android game developers. You'll start with game design fundamentals and programming basics, and then progress towards creating your own basic game engine and playable games. This will give you everything you need to branch out and write your own Android games.

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/beginning-android-games/) you can see how to set up your environment and work with **eclipse** for andriod game.

Comment: If you satisfied with the answer the you can accept after stack overflow allows you to do. ;)

Answer (score 1):

For android games this is the best book to begin with: [**Android Game Programming for Dummies**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118027744)

For learning android app development from basic to advanced level, I think these lab exercises are perfect. They start off with simple stuff and then move on to more advanced stuff. It does take some perseverance to complete all the exercises though! [**Android app course**](https://sites.google.com/site/androidappcourse/labs/lab-1)

About the programs, all you need is bundled here: [**Android SDK ADT Bundle**](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

It has:
Eclipse, ADT plugin, Android SDK Tools, Platform-tools, System image

Answer (score 0):

Visit android's developers training: http://developer.android.com/develop/index.html

Comment: Simple enough. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

eclipse is basically used to make android app, if you want to learn about android OS then xda forum is best.